# How to show a bootsrap modal popup using inside php code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display this modal popup after php condition check

```
<div id="myModal65" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in this php code used for display the popup. But it cannot display.

```
<?php
    if($intwschdle==1)
           {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#myModal65').modal('show');</script>";            
           }
?>
```

Comment: Are you using in after window.onload or document.ready?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? and are you sure this is being passed `$intwschdle==1`

Comment: and if the jQuery library is loaded. Check for errors on PHP and look at your console.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running the JavaScript before the DOM is ready? Where is this JavaScript in relation to the rest of your code.

Comment: well... you've been given an answer below. Whether that one will pull a rabbit out of a hat, is anyone's guess.

Comment: [Seems I was right all along folks...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777229/how-to-show-a-bootsrap-modal-popup-using-inside-php-code#comment61131154_36777229)

Comment: @nandhakumar the solution lay in comments and you should just delete the question. Won't serve anyone here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better if you show you modal by default and put it in the php condition like :

```
 <?php
if($intwschdle==1){   
?>
<!--full html for modal goes here showing by default - - >
<?php  } ? >
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the solution.